# Determine $\| A\|$ when we consider the norms $\|\cdot\|_{1}=\|\cdot\|_\infty$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $M$ a matrix of $m\times n$. Consider $A$ as a linear map of $\mathbb{K}^n\to\mathbb{K}^m$. Determine $\|A\|$ when we consider the norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ in $\mathbb{K}^n$ and $\mathbb{K}^m$, respect.

I have the following questions:

First of all, the linear map $A:\mathbb{K}^n\to\mathbb{K}^m$ has a explicit form?.

Second, how I understand the $1$-norm  and the infinite norm for a matrix of side $m\times n$??

Can help me in this problem, I try use cauchy inq. thanks!!

Comment: Re: *explicit form.* From your notation it seems that you are using *column* vectors. If this is the case, then your linear map is $x\mapsto Ax$. (Where $Ax$ means the usual matrix multiplication and you consider $x$ as an $n\times1$ matrix.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: As mentioned in the comments, an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ can be viewed as a map that takes a vector $x \in K^n$ and maps it to $Ax \in K^m$.

Hint 2: I think you mean "consider the norms $\|\cdot \|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ in $K^n$ and $K^m$ respect." (the norms are not equal). The definition of $\|A\|$ can be written in various ways.
$$\sup_{x \in K^n : \|x\|=1} \|A x\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in K^n:x \ne 0} \frac{\|A x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_1}.$$
For example see [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms) (scroll down to the definition of $\|A\|_{\alpha,\beta}$).
In plain words, if you consider all vectors in $K^n$ with $\|\cdot\|_1$-norm equal to $1$, map them using $A$, then take the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-norm of the result, the largest possible value is what we call the norm of $\|A\|$.

Start with this definition and see if you can finish the problem on your own.

---

Proof sketch:

\begin{align}
\sup_{x \in K^n : \|x\|=1} \|A x\|_\infty
&= \sup_{x \in K^n : \|x\|=1} \max_i A_{i,\cdot}^\top x
\\
&= \max_i \sup_{x \in K^n : \|x\|=1} A_{i,\cdot}^\top x
\\
&= \max_i \max_j |A_{i,j}|.
\end{align}
Equality is attained when $x = e_j$ where $j$ is the column containing the largest entry of $A$ (in absolute value).